# Terraform cidrsubnet function troubleshoot

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, public, subnet

I have a situation where I am trying to create some subnets dynamically with the cidrsubnet function in Terraform. Here is how I have it defined:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "availability_zones" {
  exclude_names = [
    "us-west-2c",
    "us-west-2d"
  ]
}
locals {
  availability_zone_names = "${data.aws_availability_zones.availability_zones.names}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnets" {
  count = "${length(local.availability_zone_names)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block, 11, count.index)}"
  availability_zone = "${local.availability_zone_names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}-public.${local.availability_zone_names[count.index]}"
  }
}
```

I am only trying to create these subnets in two availability zones in the region (hence why I have 2 AZs being excluded. Upon applying this code, I am getting the result I want in one of the subnets I am trying to create. However the cidr block address for the other subnet I am trying to get an address of 10.32.2.0/27 but the cidrsubnet function is generating 10.32.0.32/27. Any advice where I went wrong would be helpful.

**Planned Output**

```
aws_subnet.public_subnets[1]
  id:                              <computed>
  arn:                             <computed>
  assign_ipv6_address_on_creation: "false"
  availability_zone:               "us-west-2b"
  availability_zone_id:            <computed>
  cidr_block:                      "10.32.0.32/27"
```

Comment: What is `aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block`?

Comment: VPC cidr is 10.32.0.0/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use prefix `/27` and want your subnets to be:

```
10.32.0.0/27
10.32.2.0/27
10.32.4.0/27
```

and so on, then you have to **multiply your index by 16**, as these CIDR ranges are not consecutive:

```
cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.vpc.cidr_block, 11, count.index * 16)}"
```

Comment: The `cidrsubnet` function docs have [a section on the details of IP addressing](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnet.html#netmasks-and-subnets) which might be useful background, if it isn't clear why multiplying by 16 was necessary here. It might be informative to work through that example using your own base CIDR block and prefix lengths to see how each operation is changing the addresses.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I did see that documentation, but was still a little confused understanding it. I had a question I was hoping to get your explanation. Since my newbits value is set as 11 that means my vpc cidr prefix will have a length of 27. How would I interpret breaking down 27 bits when figuring in the netnum argument?